# Finding the angle $\angle C$ in the right triangle $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In the right triangle $\triangle ABC$, Assume $AB = EM$ , $BM = MC$ and $\angle BME = 50^{\circ}$. Find the angle $\angle ACB$.
> [image]

Here is my approach:

In order to find the angle $\angle C$, I drew a perpendicular from $M$ to $AC$ and assume its intersation point with $AC$ is $D$. Since $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$ and $MD \parallel AB$ we can conclude $MD = \dfrac{AB}2$ and in ritght triangle $\triangle EMD$, since $MD = \dfrac{EM}2$, $\angle E = 30^{\circ}$ and hence $x = 20^{\circ}$.

Although this approach is straightforward, I would like to see alternative approaches to solve this problem.

Comment: Your approach is good and it's the one I would have taken.

Comment: For a variant (using similar angles, just constructing the 1:2 right triangle elsewhere), rotate the figure $180^\circ$ around $M$. A goes to $D$, making $ACDB$ a rectangle. $E$ goes to $F$ on $DB$, with $EF = 2 AB$. Hence $EF$ makes a $30^\circ$ angle with $BD$, and by symmetry, with $AC$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In△ABC:

$$\sin x=\frac{AB}{2MC}$$

In△MCE:

$$\frac{\sin x}{sin(50^\circ-x)}=\frac{ME}{MC}$$

As $AB=ME$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin x}{\sin (50^\circ-x)} &= 2\sin x \\
\sin (50^\circ-x) &= \frac{1}{2} \\
50^\circ-x&= 30^\circ\\
x&=20^\circ
\end{align*}